# Creating Custom Generic List in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, generics, generic-collections

Hello Friends i wanna create custom generic list my code is as follows :

```
public class Dates
{
    string _FromDate;
    string _ToDate;

    public string FromDate
    {
        get { return _FromDate; }
        set { _FromDate = value; }
    }

    public string ToDate
    {
        get { return _ToDate; }
        set { _ToDate = value; }
    }
}

protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DateTime start = new DateTime(2013,1,5);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2013,2,2);

    string dayName = drpday.SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower();

     Dates dt = new Dates();
    List<Dates> list = new List<Dates>();
    int i = 0;

   for (DateTime runDate = start; runDate <= end; runDate = runDate.AddDays(1))
    {
        if (runDate.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToLower() == dayName)
        {
            dt.FromDate = runDate.ToShortDateString();
            dt.ToDate = (runDate.AddDays(double.Parse(hd_tourdays.Value)).ToShortDateString());
            list.Insert(i++,dt);
        }
    }
     grd_TourDates.DataSource = list;
     grd_TourDates.DataBind();
 }
```

in my resultant list , it only shows last item added in loop please help solve the problem..

Comment: what is dt variable, where is it declared

Comment: Also, what are `start` and `end` and where are _they_ declared?

Comment: Why not `list.Add(dt);` ? Also where is `list` declared?

Comment: What is the type of `list`?

Comment: You really need to be more clear on what it is your trying to do otherwise no one will be able to help you out.

Comment: I'd like to note that list.Insert() is an O(n) operation, whereas list.Add() is O(n) if array size has to be increased, but O(1) otherwise.

Comment: updated to list.add(dt) but that too only keeps last item of the loop please help..

Comment: @DharaPPatel Learn to debug. Run it in debug and work it out - What is the value of `dayName`? Does it only go around the loop once? What values are in `list` after each time around the loop?

Comment: why -1 here now please explain me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This :----

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime start = new DateTime(2013,1,5);
        DateTime end = new DateTime(2013,2,2);

        string dayName = drpday.SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower();

         Dates dt = new Dates();
        List<Dates> list = new List<Dates>();
        int i = 0;

       for (DateTime runDate = start; runDate <= end; runDate = runDate.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (runDate.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToLower() == dayName)
            {

                list.Add(new Dates{
                      FromDate=runDate.ToShortDateString();
                      ToDate=(runDate.AddDays(double.Parse(hd_tourdays.Value)).ToShortDateString());
    });

            }
        }
         grd_TourDates.DataSource = list;
         grd_TourDates.DataBind();
     }
```

Comment: Just to clarify what the actual fix is here. The problem with your original code is you re-using the *same* reference of `Dates` every time, you aren't creating *new* instances therefore when it goes to bind it's only ever binding one object. This is also the reason why you are seeing the *last* item in the list. This solution has redundant code `Dates dt = new Dates()`.

Comment: @Pushpendra - you don't need `int i = 0;` - you don't use it anywhere

Comment: @Bridge--- actually int i=0 is used by DharaPPatel i have just copied her code and made the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Dates dt = new Dates();
    List<Dates> list = new List<Dates>();
    int i = 0;

   for (DateTime runDate = start; runDate <= end; runDate = runDate.AddDays(1))
    {
        if (runDate.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToLower() == dayName)
        {
            dt.FromDate = runDate.ToShortDateString();
            dt.ToDate = (runDate.AddDays(double.Parse(hd_tourdays.Value)).ToShortDateString());
            list.Insert(i++,dt);
        }
    }
     grd_TourDates.DataSource = list;
     grd_TourDates.DataBind();
 }
```

to this and try:

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Dates dt;
    List<Dates> list = new List<Dates>();
    int i = 0;

   for (DateTime runDate = start; runDate <= end; runDate = runDate.AddDays(1))
    {
        if (runDate.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToLower() == dayName)
        {
            dt = new Dates()
            dt.FromDate = runDate.ToShortDateString();
            dt.ToDate = (runDate.AddDays(double.Parse(hd_tourdays.Value)).ToShortDateString());
            list.Insert(i++,dt);
        }
    }
     grd_TourDates.DataSource = list;
     grd_TourDates.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: I have the same thing, downvoted with no explanation. Any bets that it might be the guy down below who got downvoted to -5 (not that I was one of those that downvoted them)?

Comment: me too, i never downvote with explanation we are here to help each other

Answer (score 1):

The part that is causing the problem is this

```
Dates dt = new Dates();
for (.....)
{
  dt.FromDate = ...;
  dt.ToDate = ...;
  list.Insert(i++,dt);
}
```

You are using a class called `Dates` in your code, and in C# that is [a reference typ](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)e. You are creating a single instance in your code, and assign the reference called `dt` to it in the `Dates dt = new Dates();` line.
In the loop you change some properties of the instance, and add a *reference* to the instance to the list. Then the loop executes again, and you change the properties of the instance, thus changing the values of instance for the reference that is already in the list, and you add *the same reference* to the list again.
The loops continues, as loops do, and this happens again and again, and you are left with a list that has a bunch of references to the exact same instance.

So the values of the `list` not just look the same, they are *exactly* the same thing. To solve this, you would need to create a new instance of the `Dates` class each time you need to add an instance to the list, with code like this.

```
for (.....)
{
  Dates dt = new Dates(); //creates a new reference to a new instance
  dt.FromDate = ...;      //sets properties on the instance
  dt.ToDate = ...;
  list.Insert(i++,dt);    // inserts a reference to the instance in the list
}
```

Comment: It sounds complicated, but it's obvious once you grok the concept.